# How to check if a device is using RS232 or RS422?

Tags: serial-port, tty, serial-communication

Suppose we have a device which can operate on both **RS232** and **RS422** protocols. we know which serial port is connected to the device, lets say `/dev/ttyS4`.

In Linux environment using **setserial**, **dmesg** and **proc** file-system (following commands) helps to identify the serial ports and some hardware/software configurations of them but not much about the device connected to them. (am I missing something here?)

`dmesg | grep tty`

`cat /proc/tty/driver/serial`

`setserial -a /dev/ttyS[0-4]`

My question being, Is there a good way in which we can point out exactly which protocol the device is using?

Comment: RS-232 or RS-422 is implemented with a transceiver/driver chip connected to the U[S}ART.  This chip has no processor interface nor needs software control, so there would be no means of interrogating the hardware.  You probably have to provide the information manually.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for your time. So there is no way to identify the type of protocol?

Comment: If it was an embedded system that used a Device Tree, then I would create DT attributes, and look up the attributes in the **/proc/device-tree/** psuedo-filesystem.

Comment: RS232 and RS422 aren’t protocols, they are electrical interface specifications and either can be used with a UART (serial device) without any indication whatsoever to software using the UART of which electrical interface is being used.